# Find all integer solutions to $15x + 12y + 30z = 24$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm, linear-diophantine-equations

This problem is from Burton pg. 44. The hint given is this:

> Put $y = 3s-5t$ and $z = -s + 2t$

**First Question**

Why does this hint work? How did it come to be? It doesn't seem to stem from the euclidean algorithm or from $\gcd (12, 30)$.

**Second Question**

Even so, how does one proceed? Using the given substitution doesn't appear to give integer solutions, at least according to what I have done (which is probably, most definitely not the right approach). I went from $3x + 2s - 8t = 8$ to try and substitute something for $x,s$ which led to $x = 1 +2f \: \:, \: y= -1 + 3f \: \:$ ($f$ is any integer). But this leads to $t$ having a fractional value.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can start by dividing both sides by $3$, giving $5x+4y+10z=8$.

Comment: @KennyLau of course I had already done that. Just didn't include it in my question.

Comment: The $t$ should cancel out after substitution and you will be left with $5x+2s=8$.

Comment: A way to solve the equation can be given as follows (although this is not what you wanted but you may get some idea as to why the substitution works). Observe that,  $$5(x+2z)=4(2-y)\implies y=2-5t \ ,\  x+2z=4t$$where $t\in\mathbb{Z}$. Consequently we have, $$(x,y,z)=(4t-2z,2-5t,z)$$ where $t,z\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

The hint reduces the equation to
$$
5x+2s=8
$$
which can be solved using the Euclidean algorithm, or noticing that $x=0$ and $s=4$ is a particular solution. Then we get that $x=2u$ and $s=4-5u$ is the general solution.

There are other reductions. I think the following is just as simple and maybe a bit more intuitive.

---

Factoring $3$ out of the equation gives
$$
5x+4y+10z=8
$$
If we set $w=x+2z$, all we really need to solve is
$$
5w+4y=8
$$
One solution is $w=0$ and $y=2$, which means the general solution is
$$
w=4t\qquad\text{and}\qquad y=2-5t
$$
Therefore, we get the general solution to the original equation to be
$$
x=4t-2z\qquad\text{and}\qquad y=2-5t
$$

Answer (score 0):

The hint looks arbitrary to me. That's not how I would attack this problem.

After $$ 5x + 4y + 10z = 8$$ I would take advantage of "$5$" and "$10$" like so: reducing modulo $5$, it must be true that $ 4y \equiv 8 \mod 5$, or $ y \equiv 2 \mod 5$. Write $y = 2 + 5k$, substitute in the original equation, divide by $5$, and that gives you $x$ in terms of $k$ and $z$. Then $k$ and $z$ are free parameters (they can be any integers), and you have $x$ and $y$ expressed in terms of these parameters (and $z$, of course, is itself).

Comment: How does this answer the questions?

Comment: @user170039 - Fair question.  It doesn't, other than the first sentence: the hint seems arbitrary to me. I meant the rest of my Answer to show what hint I would give. My hint would be: write $y = 2 + 5k$; first, show that $y$ MUST be of this form.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ux+vy+wz=c$, with $u,v,w,c\in \mathbb{Z}$ a general such equation, to be solved in integers. Suppose that $uvw\not =0$ to simplify.

1) Put $v=dv_1$, $w=dw_1$, with $v_1$ and $w_1$ coprime.

2) Find $v_2,w_2\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $w_2v_1-v_2w_1=1$ (they exists by Bezout).

3) Put $u_1y+w_1z=s$, $v_2y+w_2z=t$. Then we can solve this system, obtaining $y=a_1s+b_1t$, $z=a_2s+b_2t$, with $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\in \mathbb{Z}$. For all $s,t\in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $y,z\in \mathbb{Z}$.

4) Replace: of course, we get that $ux+ds=c$, and it is easy to finish (and to see if such solutions exists).